# javascript - download several files

Tags: javascript, download

I'm new in javascript and i need to maintain a site.
The actual fonctionnality is to download several card into a file, one card per tab. As users can have plenty of cards, treatment can not always succeed (too many tabs), i wanted create a file evey 20 tabs for instance.

```
 var printTerm = function(grid){
     var rows   = grid.selected;
     if(rows==null) return;
     var ids = rows.map(function(val){return grid.getDataByRow(val).num_terme;});
     var nbMax = 20; 
     var nbFic;
     var idsPartiel;    
     var posDebut;
     var posFin;
     var a;    
     if(ids.length > nbMax)
     {    
         idsPartiel = ids; 
         if(ids.length % nbMax == 0)     nbFic = ids.length / nbMax;
         else                            nbFic = ((ids.length - (ids.length % nbMax)) / nbMax) + 1; 
         for (i=0 ; i< nbFic ; i++) 
         {     
                 posDebut = (nbMax * i);
                 if(i == nbFic - 1)      posFin = idsPartiel.length + 1;   
                 else                    posFin = posDebut + nbMax;
                 ids = idsPartiel.slice(posDebut,posFin);
                 a   = new Element('a', 'id':'download','href':'php/utils/export2pdf.php?ids='+ids.join(',')})
                         .addEvent('click',function(){location.href=this.href;}).inject(document.body);
                 a.fireEvent('click');             
                 a.dispose();
         }    
     }    
     else 
     {   
         a   = new Element('a',{'id':'download','href':'php/utils/export2pdf.php?ids='+ids.join(',')})
                 .addEvent('click',function(){location.href=this.href;}).inject(document.body);
         a.fireEvent('click');
         a.dispose();
     }    
 };
```

When the number of cards is less or equal to nbMax, it works well, bu when there must be several files, not: only the last passage of the loop is creating the file.
When i try to see what happens with firebug, i see my lines of treatment, but only the last is ended.
Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

If I read your code correctly, you are trying to make the browser download a ton of files into separate tabs. Most browsers won't really appreciate you trying to launch a loop of downloads that way, nor would a user really want that many save as dialogs potentially popping off.

You would be way better off packaging them into a zip file server side and sending ONE file. It would be more efficient and way more user friendly.